# How to dynamically bundle module/object in RollupJs output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

How can I dynamically bundle a module/object into my RollupJs output file? I have tried a ton off different options but can not get the expected output I am looking for.

I put together a short sample project below to help illustrate what I am looking for. The expected output should print "Hello John Doe" from the overrideApp object that is dynamically injected as a dependency.

src/app.js

```
export default {
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('Hello Mr.Roboto')
  },
  sayGoodBye: function() {
    console.log('Goodbye Mr.Roboto')
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import app from './src/app.js'
import overrideApp from 'overrideApp'
export default { ...app, ...overrideApp }.sayHello()
```

.rollup.config.js

```
let overrideApp = {
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('Hello John Doe')
  }
}
export default [
  {
    input: 'index.js',
    external: ['overrideApp'], // This is not working, expecting to pass overrideApp to index.js
    output: {
      file: './dist/app.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'bundle',
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally correct your mixing here a lot of stuff together that does not work together.

You are looking for a virtual module

### Install

```
npm install @rollup/plugin-virtual --save-dev
```

### Usage

*Note. Use this plugin **before** any others such as node-resolve or commonjs, so they do not alter the output.*

Suppose an entry file containing the snippet below exists at `src/entry.js`, and attempts to load `batman` and `src/robin.js` from memory:

```js
// src/entry.js
import batman from 'batman';
import robin from './robin.js';

console.log(batman, robin);
```

Create a `rollup.config.js` [configuration file](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files) and import the plugin:

```js
import virtual from '@rollup/plugin-virtual';

export default {
  entry: 'src/entry.js',
  // ...
  plugins: [
    virtual({
      batman: `export default 'na na na na na'`,
      'src/robin.js': `export default 'batmannnnn'`
    })
  ]
};
```

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/edit/master/packages/virtual